# Accessing original function variables in decorators

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I'm making a logging module in python which reports every exception that happens in run-time to a server, so in every function I have to write:

```
def a_func():
    try:
        #stuff here
        pass
    except:
        Logger.writeError(self.__class__.__name__, inspect.stack()[1][3],\ 
            tracer(self, vars()))
```

As you can see I'm using vars() function to get the variables which caused the exception. I read about decorators and I decided to use them:

```
def flog(func):
    def flog_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       try:
           func(*args, **kwargs)
       except Exception as e:
           print "At flog:", e
           #self.myLogger.writeError(self.__class__.__name__, inspect.stack()[1][3], tracer(self, vars()))
    return flog_wrapper
```

The problem is I don't have access to the original function's (func) variables (vars()) here. Is there a way to access them in the decorator function?

Comment: Do you mean you want all of the internal state of the function at the point the exception is thrown? If so, I don't think you can do that from a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `vars()`. The *traceback* of an exception has everything you need:

```
import sys

def flog(func):
    def flog_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
           return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
       except Exception:
           exc_type, exc_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
           print "At flog:", exc_value
           locals = tb.tb_frame.f_locals
           self.myLogger.writeError(type(self).__name__, inspect.stack()[1][3], tracer(self, locals))
           del tb
    return flog_wrapper
```

The traceback contains a chained series of execution frames; each frame has a reference to the locals used in that frame.

You do very much want to clean up the reference to the traceback; because the traceback includes the wrapper function frame, you have a circular reference and that is best broken early.